# SwiftUI - Error popup fired in multiple views

Tags: ios, swiftui, error-handling, observableobject

Im trying to use MV architecture in my project, below is a simple example of my code:

```
struct PaymentView: View {
    @StateObject private var store = PaymentStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            PaymentCreditorListView()
            /* -> PaymentFormView() */
            /* -> PaymentUnpaidView() */
            /* -> PaymentConfirmationView() */
        }
        .environmentObject(store)
    }
}

class PaymentStore: ObservableObject {
     ....
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var popup: Popup?
    
    private let service: PaymentService
    
    init(service: PaymentService = PaymentService()) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    func getPaymentCreditors() async {
        do {
            isLoading = true
            let response = try await service.fetchPaymentCreditors()
            .....
            isLoading = false
        } catch {
            isLoading = false
            popup = .init(error: error)
        }
    }
    
    func getPaymentForm() async {
        do {
            isLoading = true
            let response = try await service.fetchPaymentForm()
            ....
            isLoading = false
        } catch {
            isLoading = false
            popup = .init(error: error)
        }
    }
    
    func getPaymentUnpaid() async {
        do {
            isLoading = true
            let response = try await service.fetchPaymentUnpaid()
            .....
            isLoading = false
        } catch {
            isLoading = false
            popup = .init(error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

On each view I use sheet to show popup error because sometimes I need to do something specific for that view (for ex: calling web service or redirection etc...)

```
.sheet(item: $store.popup) { popup in
    PopupView(popup: popup) 
}
```

The only problem I have right now is when one of the endpoints return an error, all the views that use the popups are triggred and I'm getting this warning message in the console ***"Attempt to present * on * which is already presenting..."***, same problem for progressLoader, it will fire all the other views.

Did I miss something with this approach ? or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Yes. You have added the pop up to all of your views and they are all bound to the same property. Just add the popup to your root view.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't do this because usually I have to do something specific for each view after user confirm error

Comment: Then you will need a specific popup binding for each view rather than just one.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking to do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `@State` for each `View`.

Start by removing

```
@Published var popup: Popup?
```

and add to your `View`s

```
@State private var popup: Popup?
```

Then in the functions you need something like

```
func getPaymentCreditors(popup: Binding<Popup?>) async {
    do {
        isLoading = true
        let response = try await service.fetchPaymentCreditors()
        .....
        isLoading = false
    } catch {
        isLoading = false
        popup.wrappedValue = .init(error: error)
    }
}
```

The sheets would reference the local variable

```
.sheet(item: $popup) { popup in
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you call all three APIs simultaneously and show errors for all three. You need to check if error is shown or not already

```
if popup != nil {
   popup = .init(error: error)
}
```

Of course it's if you don't have any other code that tries to show something, and it depends on how you use `getPaymentCreditors()` and other methods. When `popup` is updated, `PaymentStore` updates all inner view because you use it as environment object. However, if you don't use any of the updated fields in subview (e.g. popup) when you should not worry - a subview will update update the UI in that case. It will update UI only if subview depends on the updated field.